# Vb.net cookie becomes session after refreshing page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie, and update it if exists. On the initial set, cookie looks fine and has expiration date, but if I refresh that page, cookie becomes session instead.

On set:[image]
On refresh [image]

Any ideas why?

```
Function writeReadArticleToCookie(ByVal id As Integer) As String()

        Dim sarr As String()

        Dim cookie As HttpCookie
        cookie = Request.Cookies("read_articles")
        If cookie Is Nothing
            cookie = New HttpCookie("read_articles")
            cookie.Path = "/"
            cookie.Value = id.ToString() & ","
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(6)
            sarr  = cookie.Value.Split(",")
        Else

            sarr  = cookie.Value.Split(",")
            If not sarr.Contains(id.ToString()) Then
              cookie.Value = cookie.Value & id.ToString() & ","
              cookie.Path = "/"

              sarr  = cookie.Value.Split(",")

            End If

        End If

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)

        Return sarr

    End Function
```

Comment: You didn't set Expire in else, so the cookie uses default Expire which is Session.

Comment: @mattfei actually, issue was that i was updating request instead of response cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Classic mistake. I was updating request cookie, instead response one.
Here's the code which works

```
 Function writeReadArticleToCookie(ByVal id As Integer) As String()


        Dim sarr As String()

        Dim cookie As HttpCookie
        cookie = Request.Cookies("read_articles")
        If cookie Is Nothing
            cookie = New HttpCookie("read_articles")
            cookie.HttpOnly = true
            cookie.Value = id.ToString()
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(6)
            sarr  = cookie.Value.Split(",")
             Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
        Else


            sarr = cookie.Value.Split(",")
            If not sarr.Contains(id.ToString()) Then


                Response.Cookies("read_articles").Value = cookie.Value & "," & id.ToString()
                Response.Cookies("read_articles").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(6)

                sarr = Response.Cookies("read_articles").Value.Split(",")

            End If

        End If



        Return sarr

    End Function
```